# How many odd numbers are there with one or more even digits within a range?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Imagine you have a range [A,B], how could I know how many odd numbers with even digits are there in the range?

Can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean with only even digits, or with at least one even digit? I'm assuming the 2nd one, because if you meant the first one, the answer would be zero.

Comment: The second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $B-A+1$ integers $x$ with $A \le x \le B$, of which 
$\lceil B/2 \rceil - \lceil (A-1)/2 \rceil$ are odd.
$F(B) - F(A-1)$ numbers with $A \le x \le B$ have all odd digits, where 
 $F(x)$ is the number of positive integers $t \le x$ with all odd digits.
This is somewhat complicated, but if $0 \le d \le 9$ we have
$F(10^j d) = \lfloor d/2 \rfloor \times 5^j + (5^{j+1}-5)/4 $ except that
$F(d) = \lceil d/2 \rceil$.

So there are $\lceil B/2 \rceil - \lceil (A-1)/2 \rceil - (F(B) - F(A-1))$ that are odd but have at least one even digit.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let us take $[0,9999]$  For all odd numbers, there are $5000$ of them as all the numbers that end in $1,3,5,7,9$ are odd. For odd numbers that have all odd digits, there are $5^4=3125$ of them, as you have five choices for each digit.  So the number of odd numbers that don't have all digits odd (and therefore have at least one even digit) is?